# Why does ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor no longer work when I place singleton object on a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, singleton, threadpoolexecutor

I am developing a virtual pet android application. I am new to android development. I want to put the Pet Class (which is a singleton) onto a thread to improve app performance, when I do this, the scheduled thread pool executor no longer works (whether I put it in the run(); method or keep it in the constructor as it was before... why and what can I do to get it working again? I'm really sorry if this is so obvious but I am reaching my limit and feel so silly!

The part of my pet class with the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
public class Pet extends Thread implements Parcelable {

    private static final Pet ourInstance = new Pet();

    public static Pet getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private Pet() {
        ageInDays = 0;
        hunger = startingHunger;
        happiness = startingHappiness;
        birthday = c.getTimeInMillis();
        startTime = birthday;
        messages = new HashMap<Long, String>();

    }

    public void run(){
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(0);
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ourInstance.updatePet();
                Log.v("PET UPDATED", "update method called in pet class");

            }
        }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // execute every 60 seconds

    }
}
```

and starting the pet in the MainActivity...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    thePet = Pet.getInstance();
    if(thePet.isAlive() == false){ thePet.start();}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer works"?

Comment: Sorry, the method updatePet(); is no longer called at 60 second intervals. It is called once upon starting the thread, and then never again?

Comment: Why do you create a thread that does nothing except start another thread?

Comment: I wanted to move the Pet off the main thread for efficiency, to contribute to stopping app skipping frames.  updatePet(); alters the pet variables depending on the time.

Comment: To clarify - the pet object can also be altered at times other  than when updatePet(); is called. So seemed like a bad idea not to use a second thread for the updatePet() method?

Comment: 'Put singleton onto a thread' is meaningless.

Comment: Please show the code starting the Pet thread.